# What is the amcharts 3 guides equivalent in amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts

In amcharts 3 there was categoryAxis.guides. However I could not be able to find it in amcharts 4. Below is the guides arrays which I was able to use in amcharts 3

```
var guidesArr = [{
    "category": "2016-Q1",
    "toCategory": "2016-Q4",
    "lineAlpha": 0.5,
    "tickLength": 30,
    "expand": true,
    "label": "2016"
}, {
    "category": "2017-Q1",
    "toCategory": "2017-Q4",
    "lineAlpha": 0.5,
    "tickLength": 30,
    "expand": true,
    "label": "2017"
}, {
    "category": "2018-Q1",
    "toCategory": "2018-Q4",
    "lineAlpha": 0.5,
    "tickLength": 30,
    "expand": true,
    "label": "2018"
}];
```

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nozzle/jmbyaxe1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Axis Ranges](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-ranges/) are the functional equivalent of guides in v4. You'll need to add some padding to the bottom of your chart but you can reproduce your v3 guides using your old guide array like so:

```
guidesArr.forEach(function(guide) {
  var range = categoryAxis.axisRanges.create();
  range.category = guide.category;
  range.endCategory = guide.toCategory;
  range.strokeOpacity = guide.lineAlpha;
  range.tick.location = 1;
  range.tick.length = guide.tickLength;
  range.tick.strokeWidth = 1;
  range.tick.strokeOpacity = guide.lineAlpha;
  range.label.dy = guide.tickLength;
  range.label.text = guide.label;
  range.label.horizontalCenter = "right";
  range.label.rotation = -45;
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ef2c56659a8e3559e8665fc5a933f82b/?editors=0010)